# Validating a string for a positive number, null/empty string

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons, preconditions

I have a method in which I am accepting a String `clientid` and that has below requirements:

- `clientid` can be a positive number greater than zero. But if it is negative number or zero, then throw `IllegalArgumentException` with a message.
- `clientid` cannot be a `null` or empty string. But if it is, then throw `IllegalArgumentException`with a message.
- `clientid` can be a normal string as well. For example - it can be `abcdefgh` or any other string.

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;

public Builder setClientId(String clientid) {
    checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(clientid), "clientid cannot not be null or an empty string, found '%s'.",
            clientid);
    final Long id = Longs.tryParse(clientid);
    if (id != null) {
        checkArgument(id.longValue() > 0, "clientid must not be negative or zero, found '%s'.", clientid);
    }
    this.clientid = clientid;
    return this;
}
```

This code works fine. Now the problem is, I cannot use guava library greater than version 11. If I do use it, then it cause problem to our customer who use this library so in short I am looking for substitute for this line `final Long id = Longs.tryParse(clientid);` without using guava or may be with older guava version 11. Since `Longs.tryParse` method was added in Guava 14 or later.

What is the best way to do that? Anything we can use from Apache Commons?

Comment: Why not just use a try{
}catch(NumberformatException ne){}

Comment: That looks ugly.. Wanted to avoid that.. Is there any other way?

Comment: Well, to be fair, it was 4 lines before too :)

Comment: It's a question of applying lipstick to a pig here, which shade is your choice.

Comment: Yeah that is all about. I wanted to get rid of catch block so that's why I went with Longs.tryParse earlier but if there is no other way apart from this which I knew earlier as well, then I will use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend repackaging Guava using the [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) by [relocating classes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html). In short, you can rename the packages from Guava to something like `com.example.mypackage.com.google.common` and then use those in your project.

By doing so you can use the latest version of Guava without causing dependency conflicts for your customer.

Here is an example POM based on [`jersey-repackaged-guava`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/5a149f9384e517bb8dfeee8e76b037484f3dd587/bundles/repackaged/jersey-guava/pom.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>repackged-guava-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                    <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
                    <shadeSourcesContent>true</shadeSourcesContent>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com.google.guava:guava:*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${repackaged.prefix}.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.thirdparty</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${repackaged.prefix}.com.google.thirdparty</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <repackaged.prefix>com.example.mypackage</repackaged.prefix>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Then depend on `repackged-guava-example` and change your import:

```
import com.example.mypackage.com.google.common.primitives.Longs;
```

Note that if you use this in a multi-module project with an IDE you'll want to configure your IDE to ignore your repackaged module's target classes (e.g. see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126596). Otherwise your IDE will use the original classes with the original package names instead of the repackaged ones.

Comment: I have heard of this solution. Can you tell me how will this work? You mean I just add that maven-shade plugin from the link you gave me? And then how will I use it? This line will stay as it is `final Long id = Longs.tryParse(clientid);` and only thing will change is the import?

Comment: If possible, can you provide a working example with this plugin so that I can understand how this works? I am slightly confuse.

Comment: Yes. It is basically that simple. I've added an example POM to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A bit ugly, but solves your problem, since it doesn't require any library

```
try {
    final long id = Long.parseLong(clientId);
    checkArgument(id > 0, "clientid must not be negative or zero, found '%s'.", clientid);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
```